# ClientDataSet/Provider quirk or configuration?

Tags: delphi, master-detail, tclientdataset

I have a master-detail project which uses a pair or TAdoQueries to retrieve the
Master and Detail rows, and a pair of TClientDataSets connected to them via
TDataSetProviders, and which exhibits some unusual behaviour.

Both the source tables have a few k rows in them.  On the Detail AdoQuery I do a

```
select * from Details
```

rather than

```
select * from Details where MasterID = :MasterID
```

because the where MasterID = :MasterID makes it very slow opening the CDSs because when the Master CDS is opened, it causes the Detail rows to be retrieved from the server one-by-one, which takes several seconds.

So, instead, the linking of the CDS Master & Detail is done on the "client" side
by linking the CDS Detail to the CDS Master via its MasterDataSource, IndexFieldNames & Params[0] whose name is set to the Master ID field name, MasterID.  (I imagine regular users of CDSs will be fully familiar with
this method of setting up a Master-Detail relationship.)

This works fine, except that I noticed that when scrolling through the CDS Master that there is a noticeable delay when arriving at certain particular Master rows.

A bit of investigation revealed that:

- The rows in question have no counterpart rows in the Details table.
- For those rows in the Master, the MasterChanged event on the CDS Detail
  causes **all** the rows from the Detail AdoQuery to be retrieved.  Hence the
  delay I noticed, but worse, these rows are appended to the Details CDS's
  data.  The net result of that is that for the Master rows which **do** have
  counterpart Details, the Details CDS accumulates as many copies of the Master's
  detail rows as the number of Master rows that have been visited that have no
  counterpart Detail rows (because each time a Master row without Details is visited, another copy of the entire Detail AdoQuery's data is appended to the CDS Detail's data).

Btw, sorry for this rather long-winded description, but I've tried preparing
an SSCCE that uses a pair of CDSs populated in code in place of the AdoQueries.
but unfortunately it doesn't display the problem behaviour.

So, my question is, does anyone recognise this behaviour and know what can be done
to avoid it?  Fwiw, the problem does not occur if I add the following code

```
type
  TMyCDS = class(TClientDataSet);

procedure TForm1.LocalDetailBeforeGetRecords(Sender: TObject; var OwnerData:
  OLEVariant);
begin
if VarIsEmpty(LocalDetail.Params[0].Value) then
  TMyCDS(LocalDetail).ProviderEOF := True;
```

but I can't help thinking that I've missed a configuration step which would have
made this code unnecessary.

Fwiw, I've tried versions of Midas.Dll from XE8 going back to D7 and the problem
occurs with all of them.